# How to stop a div from wrapping continuously?

Tags: html, css

My container div keeps wrapping underneath the nav div after re-sizing the browser.

I have attempted various methods, however I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

```css
nav {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70vh;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  border-top: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <nav>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li><strike>home</strike></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.php">dsdfsdfs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container"></div>
</article>
```

NAV div on the far left and CONTAINER div underneath it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
display:inline-block
```

from `.container`, so that it defaults to `display:block`.